# create one shortcut for maximize and restore window

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys

I know that super+Up maximize the window and super+down restore it.

Is there any way from which I can do both with one shortcut? I mean pressing super+up will maximize but then again pressing it will restore the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut is already there for you to use: it is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

If you want to also have <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> behave this way, then change the configuration. You can do so with following commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize "['']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings unmaximize "['<Alt>F5']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-maximized "['<Alt>F10','<Super>Up']"
```

The first command clears the default assignment to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>, the second removes the assignment of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> and the third command adds <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to toggle the maximized state, in addition to the default <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

To undo, in each command change `set` to `reset` and remove the last part `"[...]"`.

Comment: @PabloBianchi thanks for making this very important correction to the code. With respect to it not working, I made another very important correction: the keys should be single quoted, not the combination, so '<Alt>F10,<Super>Up' -> '<Alt>F10','<Super>Up'.