# Ubuntu 21.10: Cannot assign <Super><Alt><Up> for maximize window

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, wayland, 21.10

I have a custom shortcut for maximize window: `<Super><Ctrl><Up>`).
Since Ubuntu 21.10 this doesn't work anymore.
Instead it is showing me the overview.
Assigning a different shortcut seems to work.

This did work in Ubuntu 20.04 - I also have used Wayland before.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I might have found a solution via https://askubuntu.com/a/1292546/219661 which I have to verify after a restart.
I did set ``gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize "['<Super><Alt>Up']"`` and 
``gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings unmaximize "['<Super><Alt>Down']"``.
They were set to ``<Primary><Super>Up`` and ``<Primary><Super>Down`` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue where setting an action to `<Super><Alt>Down` or `<Super><Alt>Up` did not perform the expected action, but instead showed the overview.
I found this thread: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/4497

Which pointed out the keybinding that is using this is `shift-overview-up`/`shift-overview-down`.
If you no longer want the overview on this keybinding you can simply run the following the terminal.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings shift-overview-up "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings shift-overview-down "[]"
```

Now you are free to assign that keybinding to another action either via gsettigns or via the settings UI.

Note: if you have already made your alternative assigned before unassigning `shift-overview-up` you may need to remove and re-add that binding again.